# Django. Buttons stop working after fetching

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm trying to fetch text, and images from another HTML file using Django and javascript.

## HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <nav style="background: #000;">
        <div class="top-bar">
         <button type="button" id="page1" >Button</button><button type="button" id="page2">Button</button><button type="button" id="page3">Button</button><button type="button" id="page4">Button</button><button type="button" id="page4">Button</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
       {% block body %}
       {% endblock  %}
    </div>
</body>
```

## JS Code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
    const content = document.getElementById("content");
    document.getElementById('page1').addEventListener('click', function() {
        fetch('path/to/index') 
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                content.innerHTML = data;
            });
    });
    document.getElementById('page2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        fetch('path/to/info') 
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                content.innerHTML = data;
            });
    });
    document.getElementById('page3').addEventListener('click', function() {
        fetch('path/to/comms') 
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                content.innerHTML = data;
            });
    });
})
```

Whenever I fetch the data, my buttons stop working. I've created this file as a test. I'm currently trying to get texts into the content div using the sidebar on the main site that I'm working on.
Both files have the same issue.

Comment: Open dev tools and read the errors

Comment: I don't see the script tag in the html

Comment: i included the script tag up above in the entire html code,its just not here but it is linked and it fethches texts but as i said buttons stop working after fetching. also there are no errors in dev tools

Comment: Does clicking another button send a request? Maybe it's backend which fails

Comment: nope, once i click a button it fetches the texts and buttons stop working

Comment: probably after the response, your HTML is messing up (invalid syntax in HTML code)

Comment: It's not HTML, it's the issue that you must remember *always* about rebinding events when HTML or any DOM element is changing. Please see response.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you add event listeners on *beginning* of loading the page. If you are rewriting HTML of buttons, you need to add event listener for these again.

So, the code will probably look this way:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
    const bindEventListeners = () => {
        const content = document.getElementById("content");
        document.getElementById('page1').addEventListener('click', function() {
            fetch('path/to/index')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    content.innerHTML = data;
                    bindEventListeners();
                });
        });
        document.getElementById('page2').addEventListener('click', function() {
            fetch('path/to/info')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    content.innerHTML = data;
                    bindEventListeners();
                });
        });
        document.getElementById('page3').addEventListener('click', function() {
            fetch('path/to/comms')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    content.innerHTML = data;
                    bindEventListeners();
                });
        });
    }

    bindEventListeners();
})
```

Comment: Well. I've tried this and the result is still the same. Unfortunately.